# 150 percent font made text be cut

Tags: winforms, fonts

I am developing a `winforms` application in Visual Studio 2012.

I open Control Panel in Windows `7` and set the `font size = 150%`. It leads all the texts in my application to become cut. When I expand the working areas of the application, texts stay the same cut.

What in the application should I do so that the whole texts to be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are changing the screen DPI, so change the form's [`AutoScaleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode.aspx) property to `AutoScaleMode.Dpi`.

If you are just changing the font size, set it to `AutoScaleMode.Font`.

More information about this:

[Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my saved local settings :)